# Get list of discoverable BT devices with power (RSSI) and MAC address

Tags: terminal, network, bluetooth

Is there any way to list all discoverable devices in terminal? Something like this: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/28/find-scan-wireless-networks-from-the-command-line-in-mac-os-x/

I need to get MAC address and RSSI, nothing more. I checked blueutil but couldn't get what I want.

Comment: You can get the MAC address with `blueutil` using the --inquiry flag.
Then connect to each one and get the RSSI. 
The underlying IOBluetoothDevice API can only get the RSSI from connected devices.
With that functionality, you could create a shell script that performs those steps to get both MAC and RSSI values.